# ZXing Barcode ImageView not showing generated barcode Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, zxing

I'm currently working on an crossplatform app using Xamarin Forms (shared). I need to generate a EAN-13 barcode, and my code works fine on Android, but nothing happens on iOS. I'm using ZXingBarcodeImageView.
This is my code.

```
public class CardPage : ContentPage
{
  ZXingBarcodeImageView barcode = new ZXingBarcodeImageView
  {
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
  };

  barcode.BarcodeFormat = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.EAN_13;
  barcode.BarcodeOptions.Height = 25;
  barcode.BarcodeOptions.Width = 75;
  barcode.BarcodeValue = "2800100028014";

  Content = barcode;
}
```

**EDIT**

Ok, so I made platformspecific code to handles this instead, until the issue has been resolved. So now my code is like this.

```
#if __IOS__

  var writer = new ZXing.Mobile.BarcodeWriter
  {
    Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.EAN_13,
    Options = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions
    {
      Width = 75,
      Height = 25,
      Margin = 30
    }
  };

  var b = writer.Write("2800100028014");

  Image m = new Image
  {
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => b.AsPNG().AsStream())
  };

  Content = m;
#endif
#if __ANDROID__

  ZXingBarcodeImageView barcode = new ZXingBarcodeImageView
  {
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
  };

  barcode.BarcodeFormat = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.EAN_13;
  barcode.BarcodeOptions.Height = 25;
  barcode.BarcodeOptions.Width = 75;
  barcode.BarcodeOptions.Margin = 20;
  barcode.BarcodeValue = "2800100028014";

  Content = barcode;
#endif
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so this wasn't an issue in the package. Just needed to initialize it properly like this.

On Android platform, my MainActivity.cs looks like this, it is the ZXing.Net that needed to be initialized:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);
    global::ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();
    LoadApplication (new Test.App ());
    this.ActionBar.SetIcon(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent);
}
```

On iOS platform, my AppDelegat.cs looks like this, it is the ZXing.Net that needed to be initialized:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init ();
    global::ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.Platform.Init();
    LoadApplication (new Test.App ());
    return base.FinishedLaunching (app, options);
}
```

Comment: global::ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.Platform.Init(); giving me error. Net.Mobile..... not found in ZXing.

Comment: What nugetpackage did you use? I'm using   <package id="ZXing.Net.Mobile" version="2.0.4.24" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms" version="2.0.4.24" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />

Comment: I installed package ZXing.Net.Mobile.  version=2.1.47

Comment: @DipakAkhade -  Did you build your iOS version?

Comment: Yes. Its working well now. I just reinstall Zxing.Net.Mobile package. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Working for me now with adding above to launch ZXing on iOS AppDelegate, were is this even documented?